# getting value of radio button with jquery html5

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get values of the radio button selected from the list of radio buttons with jquery and change the img beneath the radio buttons to the selected filter by mending the image src url

```js
<script>
var bw = "c_fill,e_blackwhite,h_600,w_600";
 var sepia = "c_fill,e_sepia:70,h_600,w_600";
 var gamma = "c_fill,e_gamma:70,h_600,w_600";
 var full_light = "c_fill,e_vibrance:70,h_600,w_600";
 var vibrance = "c_fill,e_vibrance:70,h_600,w_600";
 var grayscale = "c_fill,e_vibrance:70,h_600,w_600";
 var gradient_fade = "c_fill,e_gradient_fade:40,h_600,w_600" ;
 
 var url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/";

 var endurl = "/v1460195911/";

 var imgName = "";


$(.kind_selection li).click(function(){

  alert($(".radio span").hasClass("checked"))
         //write your code         
         
});
</script>
```

```css
.kind_selection {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  padding: 0; }
  .kind_selection:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block; }
  .kind_selection li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px;
    width:  50px;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .kind_selection li .image {
      display: block;
      width:  50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 5px 0; }
    .kind_selection li .name {
      display: block;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #aaaaaa;
      text-align: center; }
    .kind_selection li input[type=radio] {
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="kind_selection">
              <li class="normal">
                <label for="kind_field_normal">
                  <span class="name">Normal</span>
                  <span class="image"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/h_133,r_20,w_200/fl_relative,g_center,l_logo_watermark,o_40,w_0.9/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg"></span>
                </label>
                <input checked="" id="kind_field_normal" name="kind" type="radio" value="normal">
              </li>
              <li class="natural">
                <label for="kind_field_natural">
                  <span class="name">Natural</span>
                  <span class="image"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,g_face,h_133,r_20,w_200/fl_relative,g_center,l_logo_watermark,o_40,w_0.9/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg"></span>
                </label>
                <input id="kind_field_natural" name="kind" type="radio" value="natural">
              </li>
              <li class="sepia">
                <label for="kind_field_sepia">
                  <span class="name">Sepia</span>
                  <span class="image"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,e_sepia,g_face,h_133,r_20,w_200/fl_relative,g_center,l_logo_watermark,o_40,w_0.9/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg"></span>
                </label>
                <input id="kind_field_sepia" name="kind" type="radio" value="sepia">
              </li>
              <li class="improved">
                <label for="kind_field_improved">
                  <span class="name">Improved</span>
                  <span class="image"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,e_improve,g_face,h_133,r_20,w_200/fl_relative,g_center,l_logo_watermark,o_40,w_0.9/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg"></span>
                </label>
                <input id="kind_field_improved" name="kind" type="radio" value="improved">
              </li>
              <li class="blue">
                <label for="kind_field_blue">
                  <span class="name">Blue</span>
                  <span class="image"><img width="50" height="50" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,e_hue:70,g_face,h_133,r_20,w_200/e_blue:40/fl_relative,g_center,l_logo_watermark,o_40,w_0.9/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg"></span>
                </label>
                <input id="kind_field_blue" name="kind" type="radio" value="ue">
              </li>
            </ul>
            
             <div class="modal-head">

                <img width="200" height="200" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,e_hue:70,g_face,h_133,r_20,w_200/e_blue:40/fl_relative,g_center/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg">
            </div>
```

`

[JSFiddle URL](https://jsfiddle.net/brg1zhtc/)

Answer (score 0):

The following will access the correct radio button value, you should be able to work it out from there:

```
$('.kind_selection li').click(function(){

  alert($('input[name="kind"]:checked').val())
         //write your code         

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2dwvv5Ln/

Comment: works but it still alerts the previous before the current so there are two alert boxes

Comment: I'm not seeing more than one alert in the fiddle I linked. Could you be more specific?

Comment: the tricky part is I'm trying to append to url like: http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/**c_fill,e_gamma:70,h_60,w_60**/v1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg i want to append based on radio button clicked the values of the variables

Comment: does thats make sense

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to append the value from the list of variables at the beginning of your script to the url of the image associated with the radio button below it? Perhaps if you gave me an example of the code you're actually using?

Comment: i pasted it all here, its basically like the instagram filter so everytime the user clicks the radio button it shows that filter name.  so the url http://res.cloudinary.com/hzxyensd5/image/upload/c_fill,e_gamma:70,h_60,w_60/v‌​1460195911/yhrufkspopnm6tbiyd89.jpg if you change the part of the url that says e_gamma:70,h_60,w_60 to any of the variables the result is different

Comment: ok i just added something to you code but want it like a manual slideshow and i don't really understand your code

Comment: My most recent fiddle changed the variables at the top of your script to members of an object so they could be indexed using the string from the radio input's value without using the dangerous eval() function. It explodes the current src attribute of the image above the radio button, swaps out the section where your variable goes, and then sets the src attribute to the new value.

I'm happy to code this out specifically for you if you want to take the time to very specifically tell me what you need.

Comment: like the instagram after you upload an image i want the user to select the filters and see the change as it changes in the larger image more like a slideshow http://editorial.designtaxi.com/news-flickrapp1801/1.jpg

Comment: Ok. One problem I'm having is that your radio button options don't match up to the variables at the top of the script, except for sepia. I'm moving out of the fiddle, and setting up a test page on my server, I'm gonna code out what I THINK you're looking for, in a few minutes I'll post a link, and you can tell me if we're getting close.

Comment: There's a library available for Cloudinary (https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js) that would be the best way to handle this, but I think this is a quick and dirty way to get what you were aiming for. I went ahead and coded basically all the effects Cloudinary has into this, and you'll see it's just an array which you can easily remove entries from. Just view source and you'll have the code: http://virtualstyle.us/tests/so-img-src.php. I could do a lot more with this a lot better, but I've done more free coding than I intended tonight already.